# Create random numer in excel from list but exclude numbers already selected

Tags: excel

I want to create a list of data (e.g. characters A - Z). Then I want in another column to randomly sort but to ensure that all characters are present - i.e. I don't get duplicate random numbers if they've already been selected in the cell above.

Any tips on how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Say we have data in A1 thru A20.

In B1 enter:

**=RAND()**  and copy down

In C1 enter:

**=RANK(B1,$B$1:$B$20,1)+COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,B1)-1**  and copy down

In D1 enter:

**=INDEX($A$1:$A$20,C1)**  and copy down

Column D will be the items in column A in random order

For example:

[image]

Comment: This isn't strictly random as the initial order determines which of two records comes first in the case that they get the same value from the RAND() functions

Answer (score 0):

If (!) you can be a bit manual and order does not matter...You can generate a few more numbers than needed (say if you need 100, generation 105) to count for dropping dupes. Build a pivot table on the numbers, and select however many you need.